# Removing decimal point from list

Tags: python, list, decimal

this should be very easy but I'm struggling, I'm just trying to remove the decimal place from each number in this list:

`list = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]`

The method I tried was:

`int(list)` and `round(list)` but neither worked as `only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Can anybody advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `list(map(int, list))` or `[int(x) for x in list]`  Don't use `list` as a variable name, though, because it conflicts with the built-in type.  Also, it isn't very descriptive.  The name you use depends on its purpose, but just don't use names that overwrite the built-in types.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
new_list = map(int, list)
```

Also "list" is really not a good name for a list object..

Comment: ah I only put list for the purposes of the question but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
my_list = list(map(int,my_list))
```

The map() function applies the function int() to all the elements of the sequence my_list.
in python3 map() function will return a map object so we have to convert it to a list.